# How with JS set special attribute, what will PHP ignore?

Tags: javascript, php

Is it possible to add something like a special `attribute`, what will say to PHP (or other backend language) read and ignore that input (or other form elements) and send to backend from form as empty, or not exist that part of code?

```
$("#tip").on("change", function () {
    let val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    if (val == "stan" || "kuća" || "kuca") {
      document.getElementsByClassName("hidden-num")[0].style.visibility =
        "visible";
      document.getElementsByClassName("hidden-num")[0].style.position =
        "static";
    } else {
      $(".hidden-num").children().empty(); // here any idea, remove from DOM, maybe? 
    }
  });
```

This part of code only hide from DOM this class, when I press "submit", default value from `#tip` input will be sent to back, my mission is to tell PHP to ignore that input in secound case (else part)?

P.S. When I remove from DOM that part of the form, it works how I want.

Answer (score 1):

It is odd that you are mixing vanilla JS with jQuery.

But you can use the `disabled` attribute. That will actually stop that field's data from being submitted to the processor so the processor will never even see it.

```
$(".hidden-num").prop("disabled",true);
```